# Are dialog skills used only by the selected PC or by the whole party?

Tags: temple-of-elemental-evil

The face of my group is a paladin versed in Diplomacy and Sense Motive, other skills like Intimidate and Bluff are not his strong suit.

Will they be rolled against the highest skill level in my party, or only from the character selected in this conversation?

I'm playing with the circle of 8 modpack.